# Busca em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte script de busca, funcionando muito bem, gostaria apenas que ele filtrasse a busca por palavras que tivessem no mínimo 3 caracteres.

```
<script> $(function(){   var regex = new RegExp('[\?]', 'g');   //
repare a flag "g" de global, para substituir todas as ocorrências  
$('input').bind('input', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));   }); }) </script>

     <input type="text" placeholder="Digite sua pergunta" autofocus name="query" size="16" style="font-size: 11 pt; color: #000000;
font-family: Verdana; font-variant: small-; border: 1 solid #000000">
     </font></font> <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"> 
     <input  type="submit" value="Buscar"  style="font-size: 8 pt; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-variant: small-caps;
border: 1 solid #000000">
     </font> 
     </form> </center>      </table> <table width="100%">
    <tr> 
     <td height="0" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>   </table> </div> </center> <center> <div align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">    <table width="80%">
    <tr> 
      <!--<td width="100%"><font size="3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">-->
      <td width="100%" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-variant: small-; border: 1 solid #000000">
         <script language="">

function removeAcento (text) {       
    text = text.toLowerCase ();                                                         
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÁÀÂÃ]','gi'), 'a');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÉÈÊ]','gi'), 'e');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÍÌÎ]','gi'), 'i');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÓÒÔÕ]','gi'), 'o');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÚÙÛ]','gi'), 'u');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[Ç]','gi'), 'c');

    return text;                  }

function kw_list () { this.keywords = new Array ();

this.num_words = 0;

this.query = "";

this.original_query = "";

this.query_length = 0;

this.possible_points = 0;

this.multiple = points_title + points_keywords + points_description;

this.get_words = get_query;

this.no_query = no_query_found; } function get_query () { this.query =
top.location.search.substring (top.location.search.indexOf ('=') + 1);

while ((the_plus = (this.query.indexOf ("+", 0))) != -1)

{

this.query_length = this.query.length;

this.query = this.query.substring (0, the_plus) + " " +
this.query.substring (the_plus + 1);

}

this.original_query = decodeURIComponent(this.query);

this.query = removeAcento(this.original_query);

this.query_length = this.query.length;  

if (this.query != "")

{

var query_pointer = 0;

var end_word = 0;

var at_end = 0;

while ((this.num_words <= (max_keywords - 1)) && (! at_end))

{

end_word = this.query.indexOf (" ", query_pointer);

if (end_word == query_pointer)

query_pointer++;

else

{

if (end_word >= (this.query_length - 1))

at_end = 1;

if (end_word != -1)

this.keywords[this.num_words] = removeAcento(this.query.substring
(query_pointer, end_word));

else

{

this.keywords[this.num_words] = this.query.substring (query_pointer,
this.query_length);

at_end = 1;

}

this.num_words++;

if (query_pointer != -1)

query_pointer = end_word + 1;

if (query_pointer > (this.query_length - 1))

at_end = 1;

}

}

if (this.num_words == 0)

return (0);

else

{

this.possible_points = this.multiple * this.num_words;

return (1);

}

}

else

return (0);

}



function no_query_found ()

{

document.writeln ('<link rel="stylesheet" href="gp.css">');

document.writeln ('<CENTER><P>Pesquisa em branco.</P></CENTER>');

}

function entry (url, title, keywords, description)

{

this.url = url;

this.title = title;

this.keywords = keywords;

this.description = description;

this.points = 0;

this.search_entry = find_keyword;

this.print_entry = print_result;

}

function find_keyword (the_word)

{

var the_title = removeAcento(this.title);

var the_keywords = removeAcento(this.keywords);

var the_description = removeAcento(this.description);

if ((the_title.indexOf (the_word)) != -1)

this.points += points_title;

if ((the_keywords.indexOf (the_word)) != -1)

this.points += points_keywords;

if ((the_description.indexOf (the_word)) != -1)

this.points += points_description;

}


function print_result (possible_points)

{

document.writeln ('<CENTER><P><A HREF="' + this.url + '"
target="meio">' + this.title + '</A>' + this.description +
'</P></CENTER>');

}



function no_entry_printed (the_query)

{

document.writeln ('<link rel="stylesheet" href="gp.css">');

document.writeln ("<CENTER><P> Não há ocorrências para <U><B>" +
the_query + "</B></U>.</P></CENTER>"); 

}



function print_intro (the_query)

{

document.writeln ("<CENTER><P>Pesquisando por <U><B>" + the_query +
"</B></U>:</P></CENTER>"); 

}

function begin_search ()

{

var key_list = new kw_list;

var entry_printed = 0;

if (! key_list.get_words ())

key_list.no_query ();

else

{

var counter = 0;

var counter2 = 0;

for (counter = 0; counter < entry_num; counter++)

for (counter2 = 0; counter2 <= (key_list.num_words - 1); counter2++)

the_entries[counter].search_entry (key_list.keywords[counter2]);

for (counter = key_list.possible_points; counter > 0; counter--)

{                                                                     


for (counter2 = 0; counter2 < entry_num; counter2++)

{

if (counter == the_entries[counter2].points)

{

if (entry_printed != 1)

{

entry_printed = 1;

print_intro (key_list.original_query);

}

the_entries[counter2].print_entry (key_list.possible_points);

}

}

}

if (! entry_printed)

no_entry_printed (key_list.original_query);

}

}

the_entries = new Array ();

//aqui vai as entradas para a pesquisa

//aqui vai as entradas para a pesquisa



the_entries[0]  =   new entry
(   "http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-05/#1-coríntios-14-incentiva-as-línguas-para-a-edificação-própria","1 Co 14 incentiva as línguas para a edificação própria?"," dons,
línguas, profecia ","</br> <a
href='https://youtu.be/4CbaFLqR38Y?autoplay=1' target='_blank'><img
style='cursor:pointer;width:50px;height:40px;' 
src='logos/youtube-2-1.svg'/></a>");


the_entries[1]  =   new entry
(   "http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-06/#estas-passagens-dizem-que-podemos-perder-a-salva%C3%A7%C3%A3o","15
passagens que dizem que podemos perder a salvação?"," perder,
salvação, segurança ","</br> <a
href='https://youtu.be/Kgn6sKm3sdY?autoplay=1' target='_blank'><img
style='cursor:pointer;width:50px;height:40px;' 
src='logos/youtube-2-1.svg'/></a>");
```

Comment: Miguel tente formatar a sua pergunta para ficar visualmente agradavel e deixar só as partes relevantes de código por favor.

Comment: A condição   `if (suaVar.legth >= 3)` não funciona?

Comment: John Doe Obrigado por responder, poderia me dizer onde ficaria essa função em meu codigo acima e qual a variável que devo usar, obrigado